# Wordpress CiviCRM Profile URL only showing dashboard

Tags: wordpress, profile, urls

I am using are using Wordpress 5.2.2 and CiviCRM 5.13.4

Is there a way to use the url profile links (or shortcode) like "http://localhost/wp_test/profile/?reset=1&id=4&gid=16&force=1&search=0" to show a Profile view of a specific user (not just the logged in user)?  Or should I just use API calls to grab data and build my own contact view page?  Maybe I just misunderstand the way that Profiles are intended to be used (they totally make sense for data entry forms and changing the way a logged in user views their data).

So far, by manipulating the id variable in the url, it will show the Profile Dashboard for that user id, but no matter the gid I set, only the Dashboard is displayed.  In the CiviCRM documentation [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/#linking-to-your-directory), it explicitly states that this url directory link is not implemented in Wordpress, but I can't tell how old that line is, because it kinda works?

Comment: After some tinkering and digging, I found that you can ad an "id" attribute to the shortcode to display a specific user's contact info through the Profile lens (that's how I conceptualize it, anyway).  However, even with hijack=1, the shortcode displays all Profiles for that user, and I am seeing the "Permission Denied You do not have permission to view this contact record. Contact the site administrator if you need assistance." error, even though I AM the administrator (and I checked the CiviCRM permissions and I have rights to view all profiles).  So no resolution yet, but some progress